# Linq to Entities - "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'..."

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Can anyone tell me why this works in LinqPad but not as a C# expression in my app?

I am using Entity Framework...

```
from p in Productions
join t in MaterialTransactions
    on p.Prodn_ID equals t.Prodn_ID
where p.WO_ID == 2345
orderby p.Date descending
select new 
{
    Id = p.Prodn_ID,
    Date = p.Date,
    Line = (p.ProdLine.Factory.Factory_No + '/' + p.ProdLine.ProdLine_No.ToString()),
    Qty = p.Qty,
    Wgt = (double)p.ActWgt,
    Speed = (double)p.ActSpeed,
    MaterialUsed = t.Material.Name}
```

I am getting a `System.Exception`"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: In LINQ Pad it is probable using LINQ-to-Objects whereas LINQ-to-Entities has different rules. The syntax is the same but their functionality / implementations are different.

Comment: What are the `SQL` types of the `ProdLine` and `Material` columns?

Comment: without tables and data I would guess that the Line=... is the problem, try commenting that out and see what you get.

Comment: @Belogix LinqPad uses Linq-to-Sql, see http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx.

Comment: Yes it is weird - It only complains when I try to use the result of the query.

Comment: Spot on @BlackICE. I will work around that no problem.

Comment: @AndyJohnston it only complains when you try to use the result, because before that, it's just an `IQueryable<T>`. When you "materialize" it, the "try to generate sql and send it to the db" process starts, and that's where you get the Exception. If you add a .ToList() at the end of your query, the Exception will be raised there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to concat strings and numbers in SQL server using Entity Framework 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590880/best-way-to-concat-strings-and-numbers-in-sql-server-using-entity-framework-5)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate question of what I had a few days ago:
[Best way to concat strings and numbers in SQL server using Entity Framework 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590880/best-way-to-concat-strings-and-numbers-in-sql-server-using-entity-framework-5/18590974?noredirect=1#18590974)

I created an ExpressionVisitor to solve the problem so I can write clean code and run as much as possible in a single query.
(included in answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the following line that causes the problems:

```
Line = (p.ProdLine.Factory.Factory_No + '/' + p.ProdLine.ProdLine_No.ToString())
```

This is since it combines a query-result with a .NET method result.

Maybe this will work. It delays the creation the of Line-variable-contents until after the query has been run.

```
var query = (from p in Productions
join t in MaterialTransactions
    on p.Prodn_ID equals t.Prodn_ID
where p.WO_ID == 2345
orderby p.Date descending
select new  {
    Id = p.Prodn_ID,
    Date = p.Date,
    Line1 = p.ProdLine.Factory.Factory_No,
    Line2 = p.ProdLine.ProdLine_No,
    Qty = p.Qty,
    Wgt = (double)p.ActWgt,
    Speed = (double)p.ActSpeed,
    MaterialUsed = t.Material.Name
})
.AsEnumerable()
// This is where the db-stuff stops, and the in-memory stuff begins
.Select(p => new {
    p.Id,
    p.Date,
    Line = p.Line1 + '/' + p.Line2.ToString(),
    p.Qty,
    p.Wgt,
    p.Speed,
    p.MaterialUsed
});

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert numeric values to string in linq to entities, you've got to use [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) (`ToString()` will fail)

```
(p.ProdLine.Factory.Factory_No + '/' + p.ProdLine.ProdLine_No.ToString())
```

should be

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.ProdLine.Factory.Factory_No) + '/' + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.ProdLine.ProdLine_No);
```

you've got to cast your numeric value to a double (or a decimal), as there's no overload for StringConvert taking an int as parameter.